# Getting "doesn't exist or is m2m field" error on my uuid (primary key) when trying to save in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've written my own bulk `save()` because I can't get the internal `save()` method of `ListSerializer` to call the relevant method (`create()` & `update()`) depending on the query payload. The model is called `Product` whose primary key is a `uuid`. When I call Product's bound `save()` method with the `updated_fields` kwarg, I get:

> ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: uuid

Here's `save()`:

```
def save(self):
    instances = []
    result = []

    # Note self.validated_data is a list of multiple OrderedDicts representing
    # the json of Product fields. Depending on the request, they will either
    # have uuids (so we will update these instances), or won't and hence 
    # require creation.

    for obj in self.validated_data:
        uuid = obj.get('uuid', None)
        if uuid:
            instance = get_object_or_404(Product, uuid=uuid)
            update_fields = [k for k,v in obj.items()]
            for k, v in obj.items():
                setattr(instance, k, v)
            instance.save(update_fields=update_fields)
            result.append(instance)
        else:
            instances.append(Product(**obj))
    Product.objects.bulk_create(instances)
    result += instances
    return result
```

Here's the relevant tail part of the traceback:

> File "/my/app/views/API/product.py", line 162, in partial_update
>       serializer.save()
>
> File "/my/app/views/API/serializers.py", line 72, in save
>       update_fields = [k for k,v in obj.items()]
>
> File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 792, in save
>       % ', '.join(non_model_fields))
>
> ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: uuid

Here's the relevant part of the `Product` definition:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

So, it's not a m2m, and that field does exist. What's the cause of this error then?

Comment: Is this traceback correct? It's pointing to line with `update_fields = [k for k,v in obj.items()]`.

Comment: Yes, that's the traceback. I know it's weird; I don't understand why this error occurs either. For reference, line 72 is `update_fields = [k for k,v in obj.items()]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from [this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/base.py#L732-L735) where Django compares `update_fields` you've provided with Model fields.

```
        if non_model_fields:
            raise ValueError("The following fields do not exist in this "
                             "model or are m2m fields: %s"
                             % ', '.join(non_model_fields))
```

Unfortunately the error message is a little misleading because all fields with `primary_key=True` (like your `uuid` field) [are filtered out](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/base.py#L720-L730), beside `m2m` ones.

```
        update_fields = frozenset(update_fields)
        field_names = set()

        for field in self._meta.fields:
            if not field.primary_key:
                field_names.add(field.name)
                ...
        non_model_fields = update_fields.difference(field_names)
```

That's the reason why `non_model_fields` are not empty and exception is raised.

To fix your problem, you need to get rid of `uuid` key from `obj` before saving.

```
        ...
        obj.pop('uuid')  # only if mutating validated_data doesn't bother you

        update_fields = [k for k,v in obj.items()]
        for k, v in obj.items():
            setattr(instance, k, v)
        instance.save(update_fields=update_fields)
        result.append(instance)
```

BTW you don't need this list comprehension to get `update_fields` - you can use `obj.keys()` which gives same result.

Comment: Just to clarify your last comment, `obj.keys()` returns an `odict_keys` object which doesn't have `pop()` and when I inspect with `dir()` I don't see anything else to remove `uuid` from that collection. Do I understand correctly that it is necessary to keep the list comprehension?

Comment: `obj.keys()` returns iterable containing keys from `obj` dict. If you pop `uuid` from `obj`, it will be gone in `obj.keys()` either.

Answer (score 0):

Happens due to wrong field name(column name) use in django