# How to access serializer.data on ListSerializer parent class in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an error when trying to access `serializer.data` before returning it in the `Response(serializer.data, status=something)`:

> Getting KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `<field>` on serializer `<serializer>`.

This occurs on all fields (because it turns out I'm trying to access `.data` on the parent and not the child, see below)

The class definition looks like this:

```
class BulkProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    list_serializer_class = CustomProductListSerializer

    user = serializers.CharField(source='fk_user.username', read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'user',
            'uuid',
            'product_code',
            ...,
        )
```

`CustomProductListSerializer` is a `serializers.ListSerializer` and has an overridden `save()` method that allows it to correctly handle bulk create and update.

Here's an example view from the bulk Product `ViewSet`:

```
def partial_update(self, request):

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data,
                        many=isinstance(request.data, list),
                        partial=True)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer.save()
    pdb.set_trace()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Trying to access `serializer.data` at the trace (or the line after, obviously) causes the error. Here's the full trace (tl;dr skip below where I diagnose with debugger):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 86, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/application/siop/views/API/product.py", line 184, in partial_update
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 739, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 265, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 657, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 657, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 488, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 464, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `BulkProductSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrderedDict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'fk_user'."
```

At the L657 of the traceback ([source here)](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py) I've got:

```
iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
return [
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
]
```

This made me wonder (digging further down in the trace) why the serializer.fields were not available. I suspected it was because the serializer was a `CustomProductListSerializer` parent, and not a `BulkProductSerializer` child, and I was right. In the pdb trace just before returning the `Response(serializer.data)`:

```
(Pdb) serializer.fields
*** AttributeError: 'CustomProductListSerializer' object has no attribute 'fields'
(Pdb) serializer.child.fields
{'uuid': UUIDField(read_only=False, required=False, validators=[]) ...(etc)}
(Pdb) 'user' in serializer.child.fields
True
(Pdb) serializer.data
*** KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `BulkProductSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrderedDict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'fk_user'."
(Pdb) serializer.child.data
{'uuid': '08ec13c0-ab6c-45d4-89ab-400019874c63', ...(etc)}
```

OK, so what's the right way to get the complete `serializer.data` and return it in the resopnse for the parent serializer class in the situation described by `partial_update` in my `ViewSet`?

Edit:

```
class CustomProductListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def save(self):
        instances = []
        result = []
        pdb.set_trace()
        for obj in self.validated_data:
            uuid = obj.get('uuid', None)
            if uuid:
                instance = get_object_or_404(Product, uuid=uuid)
                # Specify which fields to update, otherwise save() tries to SQL SET all fields.
                # Gotcha: remove the primary key, because update_fields will throw exception.
                # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45494046
                update_fields = [k for k,v in obj.items() if k != 'uuid']
                for k, v in obj.items():
                    if k != 'uuid':
                        setattr(instance, k, v)
                instance.save(update_fields=update_fields)
                result.append(instance)
            else:
                instances.append(Product(**obj))

        if len(instances) > 0:
            Product.objects.bulk_create(instances)
            result += instances

        return result
```

Comment: Could you post the entire traceback?

Comment: Could you post the CustomProductListSerializer also?

Comment: Then why not use this save method in your ModelSerializer itself?? Why split into two serializers??

Comment: The save method of the serializer routes to `Create` and `Update` depending on the method, and isn't suited for bulk operations. Eg it can't route `PATCH` correctly for a list of objects.

Comment: Could you post the models too?

Comment: The question concerns serializing data from a `ListSerializer`. This problem is generalisable to any model.

Comment: The exception you've got has nothing to do with the ListSerializer. It's about the source of the user field 'fk_user.username' which i think is wrong. Therefore, code for the models are useful. My wild guest is you need a SlugRelatedField:  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield

Comment: I think you should read the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point in the trace where I try to access `serializer.data` and get the KeyError, I note that `serializer.data` only contains key/vaule pairs from the `initial_data`, not the instance data (hence, I suppose, the KeyError; some model fields' keys are not present as it is a `partial_update` request). However, `serializer.child.data` does contain all the instance data for the last child in the list.

So, I go to the [`rest_framework/serializers.py` source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L249) where `data` is defined:

```
249    @property
250    def data(self):
251        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data') and not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
252            msg = (
253                'When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you '
254                'must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the '
255                'serialized `.data` representation.\n'
256                'You should either call `.is_valid()` first, '
257                'or access `.initial_data` instead.'
258            )
259            raise AssertionError(msg)
260
261        if not hasattr(self, '_data'):
262            if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
263                self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
264            elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
265                self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
266            else:
267                self._data = self.get_initial()
268        return self._data
```

Line 265 is problematic. I can replicate the error by calling `serializer.child.to_representation({'uuid': '87956604-fbcb-4244-bda3-9e39075d510a', 'product_code': 'foobar'})` at the breakpoint.

Calling `partial_update()` works fine on a single instance (because `self.instance` is set, `self.to_representation(self.instance)` works). However, for a bulk partial_update() implementation, `self.validated_data` is missing model fields, and `to_representation()` won't work, so I won't be able to access the `.data` property.

One option would be to maintain some sort of `self.instances` list of Product instances, and override the definition of `data` on line 265:

```
self._data = self.to_representation(self.instances)
```

I'd really prefer an answer from someone more experienced in this sort of problem though, as I'm not sure if that's a sensible solution, hence I'm leaving the bounty open in the hope that someone can suggest something smarter to do.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comment i still think the exception could be because of the user field in **BulkProductSerializer** class, not really anything to do with `ListSerializer`

There might be another minor error (but important) in the serializer DRF as mentioned in the documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior). Here is how to specify a `list_serializer_class`:

```
class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    ...

class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = CustomListSerializer
```

Note that it's specified inside of the `Meta` class, not outside. So i think in your code, it will not understand to switch to the List Serializer with `many=True`. That should cause the not-updating problem.

### Update - Add example for updating nested list serializer

It seems that the question was more about a generic way to implement updating for nested List Serializer rather than the actual error. Therefore, i will try to provide a sample code.

Some notes:

- If we use **ModelViewSet**, the list route won't allow **PUT** or **PATCH**, so neither **update** nor **partial_update** will be called ([reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)). Therefore i use **POST** directly, this is much simpler.
- If you want to use **PUT**/**PATCH**, then see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871396/1149484)
- We can always add a query parameter like **allow_update** or **partial** directly to the Post request to differentiate between POST/PUT/PATCH
- Instead of using **uuid** like the question i will use the normal **id**, it should be very much the same

It was rather simple

#### For reference, models look like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### Step 1: Make sure serializer change to **ListSerializer**

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # checking for post only so that 'get' won't be affected
        if self.request.method.lower() == 'post':
            data = kwargs.get('data')
            kwargs['many'] = isinstance(data, list)
        return super(ProductViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Step 2: Implement the **ListSerializer** by overriding **create** function

```
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_products = [Product(**p) for p in validated_data if not p.get('id')]
        updating_data = {p.get('id'): p for p in validated_data if p.get('id')}
        # query old products
        old_products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=updating_data.keys())
        with transaction.atomic():
            # create new products
            all_products = Product.objects.bulk_create(new_products)
            # update old products
            for p in old_products:
                data = updating_data.get(p.id, {})
                # pop id to remove
                data.pop('id')
                updated_p = Product(id=p.id, **data)
                updated_p.save()
                all_products.append(updated_p)
        return all_products


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', queryset=User.objects.all())
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = ProductListSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution I posted is actually correct, as verified with the debugger and the fact that what I proposed (overriding the data property definition in my own `ListSerializer` class. You're right that the documentation specifies that `list_serializer_class` should be in `Meta`, but the only practical consequence for me of having it as a class property (rather than a property of `_meta` is to render PUT/PATCH forms in the browsable API on those other endpoints (which I find useful, as the API is equiped to handle them).

Comment: Don't really get it: "Practical consequence" of what ? I see no extra requirements that really needs you to override DRF to provide this functionality. It is quite capable of updating partially with a ModelSerializer alternate with ListSerializer. In fact, you customize the ListSerializer just to remove the `uuid`, the rest is the same as provided here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update

Comment: Nathan, I'm sorry but you really don't understand the point of this question at all, nor the debugger output. I invite you to try to implement your own bulk PATCH endpoint with nested relationships to understand why DRF requires you to implement your own create/update logic, as stated in the docs in the section you linked to.

Comment: yup probably don't get the point of the question, it wasn't very clear. Anw, for your answer below, in the link i provided in previous comment, `instance` was used as a list in ListSerializer not a normal instance: `book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}`. So i don't think it will be an issue like mentioned in the answer. Of course the variable name "instance" from DRF is a bit misleading. I've done PATCH with nested relationship before, i agree on implementing it the way DRF recommended. Just that i don't think we need to override `self._data`

Comment: @Escher: i've only got what you are trying to do now. It seems the solution should still be much simpler than what you've accepted as an answer, so i've made an update on mine. Do check it out.

Comment: Thanks, well done on being able to look past the misleading error in the trace. There are some interesting ideas in your solution. I do have to implement PATCH & PUT, but it's a great template for anyone who needs to think about how they're going to do bulk operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error has nothing to do with `ListSerializer`, but a problem getting field `user`:

> KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `BulkProductSerializer`.
>
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrderedDict` instance.
>
> Original exception text was: 'fk_user'."

Make sure your `Product` model has a `fk_user` field.

You also have defined `user` field on `BulkProductSerializer` as writable but have not told the serializer how to handle it...

The easiest way to correct this is to use a [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class BulkProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    list_serializer_class = CustomProductListSerializer

    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
                            slug_field='username',
                            queryset=UserModel.objects.all(),
                            source='fk_user'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'user',
            'uuid',
            'product_code',
            ...,
        )
```

This should handle nicely errors, for example when `username` does not exist...

Answer (score -1):

Remove source if you are using Django auth model and set read_only=True.

user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

Hope this works for you